# Access to properties of abstract class with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an abstract class — let's name it `Base`. This class contains some properties. Moreover, I have another class, inherited from class `Base` — let's name it `Child`. `Child` is not abstract.

I want to access the properties from class `Base` with Reflection, and **only** those properties declared in `Base`.

The following code is of course not possible, because I can't create an instance of an abstract class

```
Base base = new Base();
Type type = base.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] propInfos =
    type.GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
    );
```

The following code is possible, but I get all properties, those defined in `Base` as well as those defined in `Child`.

```
Child child = new Child();
Type type = child.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] propInfos =
    type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

How can I get all properties of class `Base` via Reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoking `GetType()` on an object is only one of the ways of getting a `Type` object. Another, which works even for `abstract` classes, is `typeof()`. Using the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` option with `typeof(A).GetProperties` should do the trick.

Comment: There a further question: 'propInfo.SetValue(???, value, null)' Because I only have the type, and no object, how could I set/get a value?

Comment: @Em1 I'm not sure I follow. If there's no object, what are you setting the property on, or retrieving the property value from?

Comment: I just want to know: If I have one property of an abstract class, could I raise the setter/getter of this property (of course I have to be sure, that it will not run into abstracts methods; or is this the reason why i couldn't to that)

Comment: You can obtain the `PropertyInfo` with no problem - then once you actually have an object of a *concrete* type that inherits from `A`, you can call `propInfo.SetValue` passing in the concrete object you have.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Type type = typeof(A);

PropertyInfo[] propInfos 
    = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance 
        | BindingFlags.Public 
        | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```