# How to get Abstract type from loaded assembly C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, abstract, .net-assembly

Is it possible to get an abstract type from a given Assembly at runtime?

I am currently loading my assembly with:

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssemblyName.dll");
```

But then I want to do this:

```
Type t = assem.GetType("Enterprise.Shared_Party_PersonType");
```

My class is defined as:

```
public abstract class Shared_Party_PersonType
```

But type t is returning null.

My final goal is to navigate an abstract class with reflection and get a list 
of properties of that abstract class, similar to what they do here: [access-to-properties-of-abstract-class-with-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191402/access-to-properties-of-abstract-class-with-reflection)

Any help will be very appreciated.

**Solution:** Turns out that I was loading the wrong version of the DLL, which didn't contain the abstract type I was trying to load. However, now I know that you can navigate and manipulate abstract types with reflection as any other concrete type. Also I learned about `Assembly.RefelectionOnlyLoadFrom` method thanks to @Fuex to load an assembly in reflection-only context

Comment: Yes it is public: `public abstract class Shared_Party_PersonType`

Comment: @Adolfo Do you just need to inspect informations or to invoke/instantiate types?

Comment: @Fuex I just need to inspect the abstract type properties recursively to extract binding paths that meet certain conditions.

Comment: Ok I posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your class is defined inside some other class. In that case you must use a `+` (plus) instead of a `.` (dot). Like this:

```
assem.GetType("OutermostNamespace.InnerNamespace.Enterprise+Shared_Party_PersonType")
```

where `Enterprise` is an "outer" class or struct that `Shared_Party_PersonType` is defined inside.

Otherwise, can you access the source code of MyAssemblyName.dll? Then you might try to se what `string n = typeof(Shared_Party_PersonType).FullName` returns in there, to check if the type name is really what you presume.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen Turns out that I was loading the wrong version of the DLL. I figured out after trying what you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get any type, even an interface. Just make sure that you specify it's full name, including the namespace:

```
Type t = assem.GetType("SomeNamespace.AnAbstractClassName", true);
```

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SomeNs
{
    public abstract class Foo
    {

    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var type = asm.GetType("SomeNs.Foo", true);
        Console.WriteLine(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am specifying the full name with namespace, but returns null. Even when I inspect manually the assem.GetTypes() enumeration is not even there, but it is for sure in the DLL. I can see it in the Object Browser.

Comment: Maybe you have referenced some older version of the assembly that doesn't contain the type. Anyway this should work. The GetType method allows you to retrieve abstract types from an assembly. Even if they are internal.

Comment: That's strange, it works when my abstract class is part of the solution, similar to your example. But doesn't work when I load my external assembly with `Assembly.LoadFrom`. I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

> I just need to inspect the abstract type properties recursively to
>   extract binding paths that meet certain conditions.

Becuase of `Assembly.LoadFrom()` can have undesiderable effects the best solution if you just need to inspect type informations is to use `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()`.

So try:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("mypath");
Type t = asm.GetType("FullName");
```