# Class System.Dynamic.DynamicObject .. Why not abstract?

Tags: c#, .net

Browsing the class [System.Dynamic.DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I find it is concrete (not-abstract) class, but preventing from creating an instance of it directly by making its default constructor `protected`.

So what is the point of not making it just abstract with a `public` constructor ?

Clarification:

```
class Base1
{
    protected Base1() // protected constructor, concrete class
    {
    }
}
class Derived1 : Base1
{
    public Derived1() : base()
    {
    }
}

abstract class Base2
{
    public Base2() // public constructor, abstract class
    {
    }
}
class Derived2 : Base2
{
    public Derived2() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a good question mate. I hope someone will answer that soon, because I'm interested to know that myself too !
At first, I was going to tell you that maybe it was because only children should have access to concrete objects but abstract classes should do the trick

Comment: Well, it doesn't have any abstract methods. You only need to use the `abstract` keyword to enable abstract methods, so perhaps they simply only use `abstract` on abstract classes with abstract methods?

Comment: C# fully permits you to declare `abstract` class without any `abstract` member

Comment: keyword `abstract` is not used to restrict access to constructor, I guess it's the main point. class is not abstract but author decided to restrict access

Answer (score 2):

With a protected constructor this is possible:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass() { }

    public static MyClass GetInstance()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}    

public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    var myInstance = MyClass.GetInstance();
    var myDerivedInstance = new MyDerivedClass();

    var constructor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public,
                null,
                Type.EmptyTypes,
                null);

    var instanceFromReflection = (MyClass) constructor.Invoke();
}
```

An abstract `MyClass` can't be instantiated neither by `MyClass.GetInstance()` (compiler error at `return new MyClass();`), nor by the reflection kind (runtime error `System.MemberAccessException: Cannot create an instance of MyClass because it is an abstract class.`)

Comment: Nothing new, it was discussed with @Desolator in comments.

Comment: Sure but discussions in the comments are no answers, especially not if the comments are collapsed...

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment that explains

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables derived types to initialize a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"/> type.
    /// </summary>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    protected DynamicObject()
    {
    }
```

it's used somewhere to create objects of type `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`

Comment: At first I thought "that's so stupid, obviously you can do that", but this may actually be the reason - if you need to pass a `DynamicObject` somewhere, but don't actually want any implementation (e.g. some kind of null-`DynamicObject`). Saves you the trouble of creating an unnecessary `class NullDynamicObject : DynamicObject {}`.

Comment: @Luaan I think your comment should be good if it is an answer!

Comment: @Daniel Your answer is just the question itself, not adding any valuable information.

Comment: @Desolator I'm not agree . There is in question about preventing to create directly, and nothing about creating from derived classes, if you make class abstract you won't be able to do it anymore.

Comment: I didn't understand? If I have an `abstract class` with `public` constructor (or even without declaring a constructor, just make it uses default constructor), I can do the same. (i.e. I cannot create directly too)

Comment: you can not do this 'new DynamicObject()' wherever in that case, but if it's not abstract class you can do it in method (for instance) of derived class from DynamicObject

Comment: Hmmmm... But it prevent me too in derived class e.g. `class tmp : DynamicObject { public static DynamicObject MakeObj() { return new DynamicObject(); } }` causes compilation error

Comment: point is to allow to create wrappers with DynamicObject, WrapperObject : DynamicObject

Comment: sure, because your method static

Comment: I was wrong about methods, but you can do this `class Tmp : DynamicObject
{
 public Tmp() : base()
 {
  
 }
}` it's redundant but it allows to understand why it's needed

Comment: And again I can make the same behavior with this `abstract class Tmp
    {
        public Tmp()
        {

        }
    }

    class Tmp2 : Tmp
    {
        public Tmp2()
            : base()
        {

        }
    }` :-) :-)

Comment: can you create instance of abstract class in MSIL?

Comment: or invoke constructor via reflection?

Comment: @DanielGrankin I think any method can be invoked by reflection, unless it has SecurityCriticalAttribute, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method

Comment: @Desolator but it doesn't allow you to create instance of abstract class?

Comment: It does allow. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191402/access-to-properties-of-abstract-class-with-reflection  (unless the invoked method itself is abstract)

Comment: I'm not about invocation it, you can try invoke method which even doesn't exist. I'm about creation object. It can be used in runtime but it's not allowed to do directly.